# ScrollViewer and SetHorizontalOffset

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, scrollviewer

I use scrollviewer in my windows store application, but after calling SetHorizontalOffset function some times scrollviewer doesn't change horizontal scrolling. The same thing with vertical scrolling. Does anybody know how to work with it? May be scrollviewer scroll only for visibility for offset (I mean that if it's see that user can see offset its doesn't scroll at all)

Comment: Are you sure you're calculating the offset correctly? Make sure that the offset is less than the `ScrollableWidth/Height`. If you'd like to scroll beyond the end of your content, then you'll need to add some buffer space to the end of your content.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the ScrollViewer's offset lags by one frame.

If the below code is run every frame, diffPrevDesiredActual is always 0. That is to say, the value provided by `ChangeView` does not take affect immediately.

```
    ...
        var scrollPosition = /*some new value*/;

        MyScrollViewer.ChangeView(null, scrollPosition, null, true);

        var current = MyScrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
        var diffDesiredActual = scrollPosition - current;
        var diffPrevDesiredActual = previous - current;

        previous = scrollPosition;
    ...

    private double previous;
```

If nothing on your screen is animating when you change the scroll offset, then it is possible the ScrollViewer won't show the new value until something triggers the draw of a new frame. To test this hypothesis, try adding an infinite animation (eg ProgressRing) to ensure frames are constantly being drawn.